# What are public constants named which toggle between values?

Tags: vba, excel, switch-statement

My program is set up to function in two different modes. I have accomplished this by setting a toggle value and some public constants like this:

```
Public SIMTYPE_KEY As Integer
Public Const SIMTYPE_A As Integer = 1
Public Const SIMTYPE_B As Integer = 2
```

Using a userform, I have the user set **SIMTYPE_KEY** as either **SIMTYPE_A** or **SIMTYPE_B**. Almost all functions run a check on SIMTYPE_KEY (using **Select Case** statements) to know which simulation mode the program should run in. What is the terminology for this type of set up? And what would you call each of these constants and this toggled value?

Comment: boolean? (need more chars..XD)

Comment: This type of toggle is usually referred to as a flag. The flag is usually a boolean value (i.e. 0 or 1; which can also be referred to as FALSE, TRUE or OFF, ON)

Comment: are you referring to conditional compilation based on mode (#If SIMTYPE_KEY = 1 Then ... #Else ... #End If)?

Comment: Flag is the word I was looking for. Thanks. When would you use the word "key"? Assuming there were 3 or more toggles, then they couldn't be referred to as boolean values anymore could they?

Comment: I usually use a Boolean flag when the state can be turned "on or off". For example, `IS_ADMIN` can be used to indicate whether a user is an admin or not an admin. In your case, where you are using different simulation types, I may possibly stick with an `Integer`, especially if I can foresee a situation where you'd use more than 2 states at some point in the future.

Comment: Thanks, good advice. In this case, the constants assigned with these integer values would be called what?

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for an Enum

```
Public Enum SIMTYPE_KEY
    A = 1
    B = 2
    C = 3
End Enum
```

now you can use (e.g)

```
Dim stk as SIMTYPE_KEY
stk = SIMTYPE_KEY.B
```

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Enums.aspx